# High-severity vulnerabilities in Docker images

Tags: r, docker, image, security

I want to use Rocker images (Docker for R language) for my project and distribute the supplemented versions further. I will use Podman (rootless and daemonless) to deploy and run the containers from the images, and recommend this approach also for the further users of my code. On the Docker hub, it is said that these images contain high-severity and other vulnerabilities:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/r-base/4.3.0/images/sha256-157acbe58cb30e19974c438622faac2391e6c6e59394b7d80eb62334a3e1a962?context=explore

Okay great, now what? If the containers do not have root privileges, and they are not used as servers accessing internet, are these warnings irrelevant? What are the possible risks and how should they be managed? I possibly need to mount directories from the local filesystem in the containers.

Thanks for all the helpers!

Comment: In general CVEs are not very useful. It's more noise than signal IMO.

Comment: https://www.conquer-your-risk.com/2022/12/15/why-cve-is-not-a-good-vulnerability-management-strategy/

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question. I used a downstream image from the one you mentioned (rocker/shiny) and it had many more vulnerabilities because it uses so much javascript.

I ran a scan of the image with two security scanning softwares (grype and snyk). They found 13 critical vulnerabilities (!!).

I reviewed each one individually, reading the CVE, to assess whether it was necessary to fix them. Here are some things I learned:

- 'Critical' doesn't necessarily mean your data is at risk. It could simply mean that someone *could* DDOS your app easily, if they know exactly how to exploit the vulnerability. E.g., instead of making 1000's of requests (to flood your app), they may only need to make, say, 20 (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y) for interesting information on a similar attack). If you're a bank or massive company who loses a lot of money if your app is down for 2 minutes until it autoscales, then you probably want to ensure nobody can do this, however, if, like me, you make a shiny app for a small number of users and it's *extremely unlikely* anyone would bother to try to DDOS you, then you have to weight up whether that particular attack vector worth worrying about.
- A shiny app I was running on an internal network (i.e. not on the open internet, so nobody outside that network could access the app), and some critical vulnerabilities required a malicious user to enter very specific things into form fields, however, since nobody outside the network could access the app (and hence couldn't access the form fields to enter malicious content), I was able to deem those vulnerabilities were not a problem.
- Some vulnerabilities were only a problem if a library/function was used in an *extremely specific* way. In those cases, I checked to see if it was being used that that, and if it wasn't, and if I was quite sure it wouldn't be in the near future (i.e. until a patch was made to fix it), then I would consider allowing that vulnerability to exist unpatched.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I also read through the CVEs, and most of them indeed seem to relate to connectivity. However, I don't know does it sound odd in conventional sense, but I am probably not going to utilize the containers with (internet) connections. They are used mainly for reproducing the processes they run, executed by another software through command line.